# Visual Studio 2012 MVC 4 App Timesout

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-express, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

What would be the procedure to increase my development app's timeout process; it appears to be 60 seconds?

For detailed explanation:

I thought perhaps streamreader was timing out due to the file size but when I merely read then added the lines to a list, everything was fine. I am convinced it is due to detailed extrapolations, comparisons and replacements I am performing on each line after which EF entities are being added to a local SQL Express file..

Again I am using VS 2012 RC on Windows 7 and IIS Express, although I have IIS on the machine as well.

EDIT:

**I am not getting an error messages from VS, just IE displays "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". And, clicking "Diagnose Connection Problems" offers no reason. Upon examining the db, I see 3815 records out of 16000 were processed. If I were to shorten the text file items to under 3500 lines, no time out occurs. Nothing in Event Viewer to offer insight either. Increasing timeout on IIS default website did nothing either. I am really at a loss here and would really appreciate some assistance.**

**UPDATE: It is definetly an IE issue. Works fine on Firefox/Chrome. I tried to change the timeout settings on IE to no avail. No worries, IE is not my browser of choice anyway. Way to go Balmer!!**

Comment: Which timeout are you talking about?  Response timeout, sql connection timeout?  There are different methods depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827). Internet Explorer has a default keep alive timer. When expired, it kills the connection.